# Fedora 33: Use custom DNS addresses

Tags: fedora, dns, resolv.conf

In Fedora 32, I used to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` in order to modify DNS addresses:

```
nameserver [IP1]
nameserver [IP2]
```

But In Fedora 33 this file has been changed and it has a warning saying `Do not edit`:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

How can I modify nameservers so I can use custom DNS addresses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
resolvectl dns
Global:
Link 2 (enp2s0):
Link 3 (wlp1s0): 192.168.43.63
```

```
sudo resolvectl dns wlp1s0 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4
```

```
resolvectl dns
Global:
Link 2 (enp2s0):
Link 3 (wlp1s0): 8.8.8.8 4.4.4.4
```

Comment: Alternative way: install via NetWokManager persistently

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful.